# jenkins on kubernetes throws an error with disk space and error in loading the plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[DISK_SPACE_MEMORY_ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3rbe.png)[JENKINS_PLUGINS_LOAD_ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9dtT.png)I have a jenkins server hosted on a kubernetes cluster .There's a 99% of disk space utilized and there n number of plugins installed too.So now the problem is all of sudden the jenkins pipeline type of jobs disappears as there's no pipeline plugin ,got un-installed from the server due to shortage of memory space.When I got into the pod ,I see all the jobs there but doesn't appear on GUI .There's error in loading the plugins too.All I want is to restore the plugins back and back-up the existing jobs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by downloading new version jenkins.war and installed it. Increased the Jenkins memory as I was using PVC. Corrected all the versioned plugins by following warning messages .

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause for 99% disk space would be workspace clean up and metadata stored at jobs level. There is a plugin in jenkins that needs to be/can be set at job level to clean the artifacts and build number that is stored in master. These files are small but eventually end up occupying lots of linux space.

Worth to clean the disk and then check the jenkins for missing plugins and jobs. Although I have not seen that jobs are not displayed because of the space issue. I have also seen 99% space utilization.

At last, first you should solve the problem of space

Comment: Thanks for answering ...I will try today this

Comment: I didn't had space even to download workspace clean plugin .So had to upgrade with new version of jenkins.war to support compatibility of the plugins.

Comment: My answer was to resolve the space issue manually by purging some files/logs/workspaces etc. Once that is done all plugins would be available for use(considering clean up is sufficient). Then you can use 'Build retention plugin` --> this is different than the workspace cleanUp plugin. Anyways you have resolved

Comment: Thanks for the help and answering my question  :-)